# DateTime.now Delayed For When Setting Variable (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have created an app that has a timer functionality where you can start, pause/resume, and finish. I have link_to buttons that set the time when it was started, last paused, last resumed, and done.

The issue is that when I send a call to get DateTime.now when user clicks pause for instance, it gets the DateTime.now for when the page was *originally loaded* **rather** than when the user actually clicked the link. Ideally there's a solution to get the actual system time at the point of clicking. A possible hack would be to reload the page every x seconds/minutes to ensure the time is being somewhat accurately reflected but that doesn't seem very clean.

Code to Pause (paused_at is a datetime variable)

```
<%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pause\"></i> Pause"), task_path(task, "task[paused_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
```

---

I apologize in advance for the following code but here's the gist. User can set a time limit in minutes of [15,30,45,60,120]. If you've started a task but never paused it, then the amount completed is just time between now and start time (task.started_at). If you've paused it, then the amount completed is from paused to start time (=> time_spent). If you've resumed it, it is that time from now to resumed_at plus time_spent. The button display is based on whether things have been started/paused/resumed before and which time is more recent.

```
<% if task.started_at != nil %>
                <% if task.time_limit != nil %>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <% if task.time_limit != 0 %>
                            <% @task_remain = (((task.started_at + task.time_limit * 60).to_time-DateTime.now.to_time)/60) %>
                            <% @task_remain_pc = @task_remain/task.time_limit*100 %>
                            <% @task_complete_pc = (1 - (@task_remain_pc/100))*100 %>
                            <% @task_remain_pc = @task_remain_pc.round(0) %>
                            <% @task_complete_pc = @task_complete_pc.round(0) %>
                            <% @task_remain = @task_remain.round(0) %>

                            <% if task.time_spent == nil %>
                                <% task.time_spent = 0 %>
                            <% end %>
                            <% if task.paused_at != nil %>
                                <% if task.resumed_at == nil %>
                                    <%= task.paused_at %>
                                    <%= task.started_at %>
                                    <%= task.time_spent = (task.paused_at - task.started_at)/60 %> 
                                    <% @task_complete = task.time_spent %>
                                <% else %>
                                    <% if task.paused_at < task.resumed_at %>
                                        <%= @task_complete = (task.time_spent + (DateTime.now.to_time - task.resumed_at.to_time)/60) %>
                                        <%= @task_complete_pc = (@task_complete/task.time_limit)*100 %> 
                                    <% else %>
                                        <%= @task_complete = task.time_spent + ((task.paused_at - task.resumed_at)/60)%>
                                        <%= @task_complete_pc = (@task_complete/task.time_limit)*100 %> 
                                    <% end %>
                                <% end %>
                            <% end %>

                        <% end %>
                        <% if @task_complete_pc < 50 %>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@task_complete_pc" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%= @task_complete_pc %>%;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <% elsif @task_complete_pc >= 50 && @task_complete_pc < 80 %>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@task_complete_pc" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%= @task_complete_pc %>%;">
                                    <%= @task_remain %>% left
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <% elsif @task_complete_pc >= 80 && @task_complete_pc <= 100 %>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@task_complete_pc" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%= @task_complete_pc %>%;">
                                    <%= @task_remain %> min left
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <% else %>
                            <!--listchange.js-->
                            <% @task_overby = (((task.started_at + task.time_limit * 60).to_time-DateTime.now.to_time)/60).round(0)*(-1) %>
                            <span class="label label-danger">
                                Over by
                                <% if @task_overby < 60 %>
                                    <%= @task_overby %> min!
                                <% else %>
                                    <%= (@task_overby/60).round(0) %> hr!
                                <% end %>
                            </span>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                <% else %>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    </div>
                <% end %>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <% if task.paused_at == nil %>
                            <%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pause\"></i> Pause"), task_path(task, "task[paused_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
                        <% elsif (task.paused_at != nil) &&  (task.resumed_at == nil) %>
                            <%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-play\"></i> Resume"), task_path(task, "task[resumed_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
                        <% elsif task.paused_at > task.resumed_at %>
                            <%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-play\"></i> Resume"), task_path(task, "task[resumed_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
                        <% elsif task.paused_at < task.resumed_at %>
                            <%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pause\"></i> Pause"), task_path(task, "task[paused_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
                        <% end %>
                        <%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-refresh\"></i> Reset"), task_path(task, "task[started_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
                        <%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></i> Done"), task_path(task, "task[done]" => true), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            <% if task.started_at == nil %>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-play\"></i> Start"), task_path(task, "task[started_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
                        <%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></i> Done"), task_path(task, "task[done]" => true), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. option**
You probably should use javascript time and set it as parameter, after user clicks on the link.

```
d = new Date
d.toISOString()
// => "2014-05-30T18:54:59.092Z"
```

But you have to be careful to set correct time zone. `toISOString` returns date in UTC. And there is one more problem in javascript way. You have no idea what time have user on his local machine, so it can be problem.

**2. option**
You don't have to set time into link for pause. Why just don't set pause time on the server when request from pause link arrives? It is much better solution I think.

Comment: Thanks for these 2 options! With option 2, how would you recommend setting the pause time on the server when the request comes in? I just started programming a few weeks back and this sounds really powerful but it flew over my head. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: It is quite easy, if you sent it from a link from your example, you will have some date and time in `params[:task][:paused_at]`. So when you try to assign it somewhere just use `DateTime.now` instead of it. Or if you show part of you code, where you assigns paused_at time, I'll tell you, how to change it.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! So in my TasksController, I could technically do something like `def pause @task.paused_at=DateTime.now end` and call that directly? It seems like I might be oversimplifying somewhere. I'm updating my question above to include some more code.

Comment: Yes, you can call it directly in your controller like this. Don't forget to save it (`@task.save`), after you set it to current time ;). Do you want to know from the code something else from original question? It seems, that it needs a lot of refactoring.